scipy.optimize.curve_fit wont converge on measured data even with very close guess
I have a large dataset of diode measurements and I'm trying to extract the theoretical parameters for further modeling. I have had success with scipy curve_fit before with simpler functions but currently, it's not returning anything close to the measured data.
Here is the code I am running:
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import lambertw as W
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def shockley(v_arr, Is, Rs, n, Vt):
    i_fit = ((n*Vt)/Rs)*W(((Is*Rs)/(n*Vt))*(np.exp(v_arr/(n*Vt))))
    i_fit = i_fit.real
    return i_fit

v_arr = np.array((0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19,0.2,
                  0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26,0.27,0.28,0.29,0.3,0.31,0.32,0.33,0.34,0.35,0.36,0.37,0.38,0.39,0.4,
                  0.41,0.42,0.43,0.44,0.45,0.46,0.47,0.48,0.49,0.5,0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.57,0.58,0.59,0.6,
                  0.61,0.62,0.63,0.64,0.65,0.66,0.67,0.68,0.69,0.7,0.71,0.72,0.73,0.74,0.75,0.76,0.77,0.78,0.79,0.8,
                  0.81,0.82,0.83,0.84,0.85,0.86,0.87,0.88,0.89,0.9,0.91,0.92,0.93,0.94,0.95,0.96,0.97,0.98,0.99,1,1.01,
                  1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.07,1.08,1.09,1.1,1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18,1.19,1.2,1.21,
                  1.22,1.23,1.24,1.25,1.26,1.27,1.28,1.29,1.3,1.31,1.32,1.33,1.34,1.35,1.36,1.37,1.38,1.39,1.4,1.41,
                  1.42,1.43,1.44,1.45,1.46,1.47,1.48,1.49,1.5,1.51,1.52,1.53,1.54,1.55,1.56,1.57,1.58,1.59))

i_arr = np.array((-3.76E-11,5.83E-11,-1.05E-10,1.25E-10,-2.45E-11,-1.75E-11,-1.26E-11,-1.01E-11,-9.41E-12,-1.04E-11,
                  -9.47E-12,-9.03E-12,-1.03E-11,-9.54E-12,-7.91E-12,-9.89E-12,-1.65E-11,1.59E-10,-5.90E-11,-1.17E-11,
                  -1.09E-11,-7.61E-12,-2.86E-12,-8.39E-12,-7.87E-12,-7.91E-12,-6.43E-12,-6.87E-12,1.48E-12,-7.25E-12,
                  -6.58E-12,-5.73E-12,-5.39E-12,-3.99E-12,-2.34E-12,-1.08E-12,2.06E-12,3.01E-12,8.24E-12,1.36E-11,
                  2.26E-11,2.99E-11,4.11E-11,6.32E-11,8.54E-11,1.16E-10,1.53E-10,2.09E-10,2.73E-10,3.65E-10,4.93E-10,
                  6.32E-10,8.46E-10,1.09E-09,1.42E-09,1.85E-09,2.41E-09,3.09E-09,3.98E-09,5.16E-09,6.61E-09,8.36E-09,
                  1.10E-08,1.43E-08,1.84E-08,2.39E-08,3.11E-08,4.05E-08,5.41E-08,6.95E-08,9.13E-08,1.19E-07,1.57E-07,
                  2.08E-07,2.79E-07,3.71E-07,4.94E-07,6.57E-07,8.83E-07,1.19E-06,1.61E-06,2.19E-06,3.00E-06,4.12E-06,
                  5.72E-06,7.91E-06,1.10E-05,1.54E-05,2.16E-05,3.03E-05,4.23E-05,5.87E-05,8.09E-05,0.000110276,
                  0.000148352,0.00019647,0.000256439,0.000329539,0.000416616,0.000519519,0.000638944,0.000775399,
                  0.000930671,0.001105803,0.001299725,0.001514556,0.001750505,0.002006911,0.00228582,0.002586988,
                  0.002909377,0.003255466,0.003622608,0.004013351,0.004426898,0.004860486,0.005317697,0.005796602,
                  0.006294098,0.006813415,0.007352292,0.007908308,0.008483431,0.009075115,0.009680456,0.01030162,
                  0.01094043,0.01158479,0.01224334,0.01290703,0.01358056,0.01426283,0.01494866,0.01564087,0.01633509,
                  0.01703126,0.01773028,0.01843017,0.01912786,0.01982758,0.0205251,0.02121851,0.02191115,0.0226002,
                  0.02328385,0.02396644,0.02464198,0.02531404,0.02598236,0.02664429,0.02730172,0.02795239,0.02859697,
                  0.02923778,0.02987059,0.02999878,0.02999881,0.02999872,0.02999867,0.02999871))

guessIs = 2e-9
guessRs = 14.5
guessn = 1.3
guessVt = 0.026

guess_fit = shockley(v_arr, guessIs, guessRs, guessn,guessVt)

plt.plot(v_arr, guess_fit, label='guess')
plt.plot(v_arr, i_arr, label='data')

guess = np.array([guessIs, guessRs, guessn, guessVt])

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(shockley, v_arr, i_arr, p0=guess, bounds=((2e-9, 0, 1, 0),(1, 20, 2, 1)))
Is, Rs, n, Vt = popt
print(f'Is={Is}, Rs={Rs}, n={n}, Vt={Vt}')

test = shockley(v_arr, Is, Rs, n, Vt)

fit = shockley(v_arr, Is, Rs, n , Vt)
plt.plot(v_arr, fit, label='fit')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('V')
plt.xlabel('I')
plt.legend()
plt.show()



The plots show that the initial guess is quite close but the fit always diverges. I have added bounds that help a bit but I don't know what variability my results are going to have so I can't have them too tight.
I have tried changing the method to 'dogbox' and 'lm' (as per this example). 'dogbox' gets closest but seems to just follow the guess.

Add your plot screenshots to the question. Since you don't have enough rep to turn the imgur links into embeds, someone else will.

And please add labeled axes and a legend to the plots. I can't tell what I'm looking at when I run the code.

I have added the suggested items. I have also changed the order of the arguments for the optimization as suggested by @jared which helped by as suggested by Reinderien plotting in semi-log shows that the fit is still poor for the exponential function.

This is not a linear dataset (or function); a linear fit is not appropriate - or perhaps more specifically, a linear fit is not the first fit you should perform; you can use it as a secondary finishing step.
Since the data are exponential, it's crucial that they be plotted on a semilog scale, which will make it obvious that your fit is way out of whack. Exponential functions are very touchy when it comes to initial conditions; I demonstrate how to use sliders to get "in the neighbourhood" by hand to choose initial conditions.
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from scipy.special import lambertw as W
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def shockley(
    v: np.ndarray,
    Is: float,
    Rs: float,
    n: float,
    Vt: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    i_fit = (
        n*Vt/Rs
    )*W(
        Is*Rs/(n*Vt)
        *np.exp(v/(n*Vt))
    )
    return i_fit.real


def shockley_log(
    v: np.ndarray,
    Is: float,
    Rs: float,
    n: float,
    Vt: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.log(shockley(v, Is, Rs, n, Vt))


def load_data() -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    v_arr = np.arange(0, 1.6, 0.01)

    i_arr = np.array((
        -3.76E-11,5.83E-11,-1.05E-10,1.25E-10,-2.45E-11,-1.75E-11,-1.26E-11,-1.01E-11,-9.41E-12,-1.04E-11,
        -9.47E-12,-9.03E-12,-1.03E-11,-9.54E-12,-7.91E-12,-9.89E-12,-1.65E-11,1.59E-10,-5.90E-11,-1.17E-11,
        -1.09E-11,-7.61E-12,-2.86E-12,-8.39E-12,-7.87E-12,-7.91E-12,-6.43E-12,-6.87E-12,1.48E-12,-7.25E-12,
        -6.58E-12,-5.73E-12,-5.39E-12,-3.99E-12,-2.34E-12,-1.08E-12,2.06E-12,3.01E-12,8.24E-12,1.36E-11,
        2.26E-11,2.99E-11,4.11E-11,6.32E-11,8.54E-11,1.16E-10,1.53E-10,2.09E-10,2.73E-10,3.65E-10,4.93E-10,
        6.32E-10,8.46E-10,1.09E-09,1.42E-09,1.85E-09,2.41E-09,3.09E-09,3.98E-09,5.16E-09,6.61E-09,8.36E-09,
        1.10E-08,1.43E-08,1.84E-08,2.39E-08,3.11E-08,4.05E-08,5.41E-08,6.95E-08,9.13E-08,1.19E-07,1.57E-07,
        2.08E-07,2.79E-07,3.71E-07,4.94E-07,6.57E-07,8.83E-07,1.19E-06,1.61E-06,2.19E-06,3.00E-06,4.12E-06,
        5.72E-06,7.91E-06,1.10E-05,1.54E-05,2.16E-05,3.03E-05,4.23E-05,5.87E-05,8.09E-05,0.000110276,
        0.000148352,0.00019647,0.000256439,0.000329539,0.000416616,0.000519519,0.000638944,0.000775399,
        0.000930671,0.001105803,0.001299725,0.001514556,0.001750505,0.002006911,0.00228582,0.002586988,
        0.002909377,0.003255466,0.003622608,0.004013351,0.004426898,0.004860486,0.005317697,0.005796602,
        0.006294098,0.006813415,0.007352292,0.007908308,0.008483431,0.009075115,0.009680456,0.01030162,
        0.01094043,0.01158479,0.01224334,0.01290703,0.01358056,0.01426283,0.01494866,0.01564087,0.01633509,
        0.01703126,0.01773028,0.01843017,0.01912786,0.01982758,0.0205251,0.02121851,0.02191115,0.0226002,
        0.02328385,0.02396644,0.02464198,0.02531404,0.02598236,0.02664429,0.02730172,0.02795239,0.02859697,
        0.02923778,0.02987059,0.02999878,0.02999881,0.02999872,0.02999867,0.02999871,
    ))

    return v_arr, i_arr


def fit(
    v: np.ndarray,
    i: np.ndarray,
    guessIs: float = 2e-16,
    guessRs: float = 15,
    guessn: float = 0.2,
    guessVt: float = 0.2,
) -> tuple[
     np.ndarray,
     np.ndarray,
     np.ndarray,
]:
    p0 = np.array((guessIs, guessRs, guessn, guessVt))
    i_guess = shockley(v, *p0)

    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
        f=shockley_log,
        xdata=v, ydata=np.log(i), p0=p0,
        # bounds=(
        #     (1e-16, 0, 0.05, 0),
        #     (1e-9, 20, 1, 1),
        # ),
        method='lm',
    )
    i_fit = shockley(v, *popt)
    return popt, i_guess, i_fit


def plot(
    v: np.ndarray,
    i: np.ndarray,
    i_guess: np.ndarray,
    i_fit: np.ndarray,
) -> tuple[plt.Figure, Slider, Slider, Slider, Slider]:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.semilogy(v, i, label='experiment')
    ax.semilogy(v[:i_guess.size], i_guess, label='estimate')
    ax.semilogy(v[:i_fit.size], i_fit, label='fit')
    ax.set_xlabel('v')
    ax.set_ylabel('i')
    ax.legend()

    return fig


def show_sliders(
    v: np.ndarray,
    i: np.ndarray,
) -> plt.Figure:
    fig: plt.Figure
    ax: plt.Axes
    fig, (ax, *slider_axes) = plt.subplots(ncols=5)
    p0 = 1e-9, 20, 0.2, 0.2
    ax.semilogy(v, i, label='experiment')
    line, = ax.semilogy(v, shockley(v, *p0), label='parametric')
    ax.set_xlabel('v')
    ax.set_ylabel('i')

    is_slider = Slider(
        ax=slider_axes[0], label='Is', valmin=-20, valmax=-9, valinit=-16, orientation='vertical',
    )
    rs_slider = Slider(
        ax=slider_axes[1], label='Rs', valmin=0.1, valmax=100, valinit=p0[1], orientation='vertical',
    )
    n_slider = Slider(
        ax=slider_axes[2], label='n', valmin=0.01, valmax=0.5, valinit=p0[2], orientation='vertical',
    )
    vt_slider = Slider(
        ax=slider_axes[3], label='Vt', valmin=0, valmax=1, valinit=p0[3], orientation='vertical',
    )

    def update(val):
        line.set_ydata(shockley(v, 10**is_slider.val, rs_slider.val, n_slider.val, vt_slider.val))
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    is_slider.on_changed(update)
    rs_slider.on_changed(update)
    n_slider.on_changed(update)
    vt_slider.on_changed(update)

    return fig, is_slider, rs_slider, n_slider, vt_slider


def main() -> None:
    v, i = load_data()
    section = (v > 0.3) & (i > 0)
    v = v[section]
    i = i[section]

    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
    # fig, *sliders = show_sliders(v, i)

    popt, i_guess, i_fit = fit(v=v, i=i)
    (Is, Rs, n, Vt) = popt
    print(f'Is={Is}, Rs={Rs}, n={n}, Vt={Vt}')

    plot(v, i, i_guess, i_fit)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Is=1.8087970458977566e-16, Rs=14.46916151330944, n=1.0978775079999148, Vt=0.031461129386302314


Further: notice that n and Vt are not meaningfully distinct degrees of freedom, since they always appear as a product in the Shockley equation. That means that you can choose any value for n and you could still fit a Vt to appear correct. For your purposes, you can just merge those two variables to a single nVt during fit - or better, fix Vt at the thermal voltage for standard ambient temperature - 25.85 mV - and only optimise on n. This gets you closer to
Is=1.8087964456455226e-16, Rs=14.469165848153489, n=1.336188473508956


Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the sliders don't work in my environment because I am using pycharm and it has a problem with the pyqt back end.
I need Vt to be variable because the dataset I am using has data at different temperatures.
While the sliders give an indication of how to get a close first guess it won't really work with a varying dataset. I suppose I need a better way to fit the exponential data. I will update my post when I come up with something. Thanks again.

@scott_R if the Qt backend doesn't work, then... Don't use it. TkAgg is more portable. As to Vt - if you do not know your temperatures, and you know they vary significantly, then you can never ever meaningfully separate them from n.

I finally managed to get back to this. I found that the temperature was embedded in the data so I managed to calculate Vt for the given circumstances. Using an appropriate guess your code now fits to all my data and I can loop through it and extract Rs with a reasonable confidence. Thanks very much.

As per the documentation, scipy.optimize.curve_fit expects the function signature to be f(x, a, b, c, d), but you have defined it as f(a, x, b, c, d). Correct the ordering (and fix the other locations where it is used) and it will work as expected.
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import lambertw as W
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def shockley(v_arr, Is, Rs, n, Vt):
    i_fit = ((n*Vt)/Rs)*W(((Is*Rs)/(n*Vt))*(np.exp(v_arr/(n*Vt))))
    i_fit = i_fit.real
    return i_fit

guessIs = 3e-9
guessRs = 11
guessn = 1.7
guessVt = 0.044

guess_fit = shockley(v_arr, guessIs, guessRs, guessn,guessVt)

plt.plot(v_arr, i_arr, label="Data")
plt.plot(v_arr, guess_fit, label="Guess")

guess = np.array([guessIs, guessRs, guessn, guessVt])

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(shockley, v_arr, i_arr, 
                                      p0=guess, 
                                      bounds=((2e-9, 0, 1, 0), (1, 20, 2, 1)))
Is, Rs, n, Vt = popt
print(f'Is={Is}, Rs={Rs}, n={n}, Vt={Vt}')

test = shockley(v_arr, Is, Rs, n, Vt)

fit = shockley(v_arr, Is, Rs, n , Vt)
plt.plot(v_arr, fit, label="Fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Print out:
Is=2.904220083107052e-09, Rs=10.900911685026195, n=1.700117900138838, Vt=0.04438584374368413


